# Long integer number doesn't work for power of 8 in C++

Tags: c++, long-integer

I am trying to solve [geeksforgeeks](http://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/check-if-a-integer-is-power-of-8-or-not/0) test case that **Check if a Integer is power of 8 or not.**

I have made test case using c++. In this program, when I provide long integer number like `8589934592`. But, condition become `false` and test case failed.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    unsigned int n, n1;
    cin>>n; // Denoting the number of test cases

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin>>n1; // An integer number

        while(n1 > 8)
        {
            n1 = n1 / 8;
        }

        if(n1 == 8)
        {
            cout<<"Yes"<<endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"No"<<endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So, Why test case does not work for long power of eight number?

Here is sample input:

```
2
307163648379016
8589934592
```

And desired output:

```
No
Yes
```

Comment: Your input number is bigger than the biggest possible value for `unsigned int`. You could try `uint64_t` as the type

Comment: C++ is statically typed. `cin` won't magically transform n or n1 into a `long` integer.

Comment: @M.M that also not work for long number like : 307163648379016

Comment: What do you expect? All fundamental integral types have a fixed range. If you want unlimited range, use a BIgInt library.

Comment: @Jayesh It does work for that number (with `uint64_t` instead of `unsigned int`)

Comment: Does your code fail with a wrong result? Or does it fail because of being too slow? The latter is very common with challenges like that.

Comment: @Yunnosch it is failed with wrong result.

Comment: What is the correct result for 307163648379016  and 8589934592?

Comment: That's the challenge. Figure out the problem, then solve it. If you let others do it for you, where's the fun?

Comment: 8589934592 is power of eight but I getting output not power of eight and 307163648379016 is not power of eight but I getting power of eight.

Comment: @n.m. Yes sir, I tried more than 2hrs but I am failed.

Comment: Did you try https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/, or gdb, or printing a lot?

Comment: @Jayesh 2hrs - that's really long ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some correction in my test case and solved that problem.

First I have used `%` operator instead of `/` operator in `while()` loop condition which was silly mistake made by me.
Then, I have changed if number is equal to 1 then number is power of eight else number not power of eight.

My perfect working code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    uint64_t n, n1;
    cin>>n; // Denoting the number of test cases

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin>>n1; // An integer number

        while(n1%8 == 0)
        {
            n1 = n1 / 8;
        }

        if(n1 == 1)
        {
            cout<<"Yes"<<endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"No"<<endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Input:**

```
2
307163648379016
8589934592
```

**Output:**

```
No
Yes
```

Thank you very much @[Yunnosch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7733418/yunnosch) to help me.

Answer (score 1):

A little change to your code shows the intermediate results.
They are very interesting, indicating where your code goes wrong in a much too generous way.
It does so for not so long numbers as well by the way. ;-)

Since this is a question about a challenge, I will provide only the modified code to give you the right idea.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    uint64_t n, n1;
    cin>>n; // Denoting the number of test cases
    cout << n << endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin>>n1; // An integer number
        cout << n1 << endl;

        while(n1 / 8)
        {
            n1 = n1 / 8;
            cout << n1 << endl;
        }

        if(n1 == 8)
        {
            cout<<"Yes"<<endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"No"<<endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
3
3
69
69
8
Yes
8589934592
8589934592
1073741824
134217728
16777216
2097152
262144
32768
4096
512
64
8
Yes
307163648379016
307163648379016
38395456047377
4799432005922
599929000740
74991125092
9373890636
1171736329
146467041
18308380
2288547
286068
35758
4469
558
69
8
Yes
```

May I recommend to learn debugging?
The art of debugging can make very good use of a debugger program, but the more important debugger should be between monitor and keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Can't we just compare bits to determine whether it's a power of 8?

```
#include <limits>

constexpr unsigned long long pow8bits()
{
    unsigned long long result = 0;

    for (unsigned i = 3 ; i < std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long>::digits ; ++i)
    {
        result |= static_cast<unsigned long long>(1) << i;
    }

    return result;
}

bool is_power_of_8(unsigned long long val)
{
    return (val & pow8bits()) != 0 
           and (val & ~pow8bits()) == 0;
}
```